# Jquery querySelectorAll using other property than class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find an element with specified name using this code:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=" + data['res'] + "]");
```

The problem is that when

```
data['res']
```

contains string that include space, the following error is displayed:

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: Could you replace the space with an underscore (`_`)?

Comment: Because you do not quote it....

Comment: It is weird your name would have a string in it.

Comment: I don't see jQuery here.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=\"" + data['res'] + "\"]");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the value first:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="` + data['res'] + `"]`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not quote the value

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='" + data['res'] + "']");
```

If you can use string literals, it would be a good use case to use it.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${data['res']}"]`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the value in single quotes. If you're doing it with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=" + data['res'] + "]");
// let's say data['res'] = 'name with a space'
// value would be "input[name=name with a space]" -- invalid
```

You'll get an invalid value because of the lack of quoting.

You can put single quotes after "name=" and before "]":

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='" + data['res'] + "']");
// value would be "input[name='name with a space']" -- valid
```